# How to delete database login in crystal report

Tags: asp.net, webforms, crystal-reports

I got problem on my reporting tools, I can not parse the data for database logon in crystal report, but it's still showing parse parameter for logon
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OFYTM.png)

And here is my code that I tried:

```
public partial class frm_coba_report : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var path = @"D:\CronosERP\Report 
         Cronos\ReportWebMVC\ReportWebMVC\Report\CobaReport.rpt";
        var filename = "CobaReport.rpt";
        var vPath = path.Replace(@"D:\CronosERP\Report 
         Cronos\ReportWebMVC\Report", "~").Replace(@"\","/");
        ReportDocument report = new ReportDocument();
        report.Load(Server.MapPath("~/Report/CobaReport.rpt"));
        CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = report;
        report.SetDatabaseLogon("", "", @"LAPTOP-H6ISNS0P\SQLEXPRESS", 
        "CronosDB_Mondrian", false);
        // report.SetDatabaseLogon("sa","123456", "192.168.1.98,3306", 
        //"CronosDB_Mondrian", false);

        //var connectionInfo = new ConnectionInfo();
        //connectionInfo.ServerName = @"LAPTOP-H6ISNS0P\SQLEXPRESS";
        //connectionInfo.DatabaseName = "CronosDB_Mondrian";
        //connectionInfo.UserID = "";
        //connectionInfo.Password = "";
        //connectionInfo.IntegratedSecurity = false;

        //for (int i = 0; i < CrystalReportViewer1.LogOnInfo.Count; i++)
        //{
        //    CrystalReportViewer1.LogOnInfo[i].ConnectionInfo = 
           // connectionInfo;
        //}
    }
}
```

So could anybody help me how to delete the logon in crystal report?

Comment: Are the connection setting sections meant to be commented out?

Comment: I've tried those but not work,. the uncommented is the other method I tried